# Vehicle Speed Estimation via Blob Opencv C++

Tags: opencv, c++11

```
bool checkIfBlobsCrossedTheLine2(std::vector<Blob> &blobs, int &intHorizontalLinePosition,int &intHorizontalLinePosition2, cv::Mat &imgFrame2Copy) {

    bool blnAtLeastOneBlobCrossedTheLine = false;
    for (auto blob : blobs) {

        if (blob.blnStillBeingTracked == true && blob.centerPositions.size() >= 2) {
            int prevFrameIndex = (int)blob.centerPositions.size() - 2;
            int currFrameIndex = (int)blob.centerPositions.size() - 1;



            if ((blob.centerPositions[prevFrameIndex].y > intHorizontalLinePosition && blob.centerPositions[currFrameIndex].y <= intHorizontalLinePosition)&&(blob.centerPositions[prevFrameIndex].y > intHorizontalLinePosition2 && blob.centerPositions[currFrameIndex].y <= intHorizontalLinePosition2)) {

            int time = 30;
            int distance = 200;
            int speed = distance/time;
            double dblFontScale = blobs[currFrameIndex].dblCurrentDiagonalSize / 10.0;
            int intFontThickness = (int)std::round(dblFontScale * 1.0);
            std::cout<<"Speed: "<<speed<<std::endl;

            cv::putText(imgFrame2Copy, std::to_string(speed), blobs[currFrameIndex].centerPositions.back(), CV_FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, dblFontScale, SCALAR_RED, intFontThickness);
            blnAtLeastOneBlobCrossedTheLine = true;
            }

        }

    } 

    return blnAtLeastOneBlobCrossedTheLine;
}
```

Please I didn't understand why I can't display the speed of each vehicle,
so help please

Comment: Have you debugged? If you put a breakpoint before the `cv::putText` call, do you reach it? If not, maybe your `y` movement direction is wrong. In any case, show what you've tried to do to debug this.

Comment: Hello Sir thank you for your answer, yes i have debugged even with the fixed values of the time and the distance i couldn't display the speed for each car, here is the positions of my two crossing lines :

Comment: int intHorizontalLinePosition = (int)std::round((double)imgFrame1.rows * 0.17);

    crossingLine[0].x = 0;
    crossingLine[0].y = intHorizontalLinePosition;

    crossingLine[1].x = imgFrame1.cols - 1;
    crossingLine[1].y = intHorizontalLinePosition;
    
    //////crossing Line2
    
    int intHorizontalLinePosition2 = (int)std::round((double)imgFrame1.rows * 0.7);

    crossingLine2[0].x = 0;
    crossingLine2[0].y = intHorizontalLinePosition2;

    crossingLine2[1].x = imgFrame1.cols - 1;
    crossingLine2[1].y = intHorizontalLinePosition2;

Comment: does this work? `cv::putText(imgFrame2Copy, "testval " + std::to_string(100), cv::Point(10,10), CV_FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 10, SCALAR_RED, 2);` ? What are the values of `dblFontScale` and `intFontThickness` for your blobs? can you plot them in the cout line?

Comment: sorry for being late !
is there any relation between the position of the blob in the frame and the speed, because i can find the position of the vehicle in the frame !